# Add a statement for a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a label named "direction". I have a map with a lot of pins. When i click on one pin and tap the label "direction" it give me two options and works fine. But when i do not click on a Pin and tap de label "direction" the app crash.

i want to setup an statement when the a pin is not selected an alert show that the user first select a pin to get directions.

Hope someone can look at code to make this possible:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {




    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!




    @IBAction func MapType(sender: AnyObject) {
        let segmentedControl = sender as! UISegmentedControl
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid
        default:
            mapView.mapType = mapView.mapType
        }
    }


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        //3
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        var Marker= GMSMarker()
        Marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(5.2317, 4.5708 )
        Marker.title = "1"
        Marker.snippet = "1"
        Marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        Marker.map = mapView

        var Marker1= GMSMarker()
        Marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(5.2317, 8.5708 )
        Marker1.title = "2"
        Marker1.snippet = "2"
        Marker1.map = mapView      



        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - 100, view.frame.size.height - 40, 80, 30))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.text = "direction"
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "directionTapped")
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)




        mapView!.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
        mapView!.addSubview(label)
        mapView!.bringSubviewToFront(label)

        self.view.addSubview(label)

    }

    func directionTapped() {
        let openMapsActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Open in Maps", message: "Choose a maps application", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude, self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
            let item = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
            let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:
                MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]
            item.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        }))
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
            } else {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
            }
        }))
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(openMapsActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




    // 1
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // 2
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

            // 3
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            //4
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    // 5
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {

            // 6
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 6, bearing: 1, viewingAngle: 1)

            // 7
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: try the tap line like this:
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "directionTapped:")
and the action like this:
func directionTapped(sender:AnyObject?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of the complete code, here is what i can extrapolate:

1. I am assuming you have a mapView that is already set.
2. I am assuming mapView!.selectedMarker gets populated only when the user selects the pin, else it is nil (or some other value u choose)  then,

Now, directionTapped should be:

```
if self.mapView!.selectedMarker != nil {
  <Your current Code>
} else {
  <Code to Show the new alert about pin not selected>
}
```

Comment: i have edit my queston with the completed code in ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

with this code it worked from me:

```
func directionTapped(){
    //code input from Apple-and-Oranges
            if self.mapView!.selectedMarker != nil {
    //current code
            let openMapsActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Open in Maps", message: "Choose a maps application", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
              openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                  let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude, self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
                    let item = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
                    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:
                        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                        MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]
                    item.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options as [NSObject : AnyObject])
                }))
                openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                  if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                        "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
                   } else {
                      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                         "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
                   }
                }))
               openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
               presentViewController(openMapsActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    //Added a alert message
            else {


                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Pin!", message: "\nChoose Pin to get navigation from current location", preferredStyle: .Alert)


                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                }))

                presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            }
```